# Шаблонизатор Ltpl

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы

К сожалению, не знаю, уместны ли на Хэшкоде вопросы такого типа. Написал недавно шаблонизатор на php и хотелось бы услышать ваши мнения о нем.
Шаблонизатор фактически состоит из одного файла и служит для отделения логики от представления. Плюс, в него добавлено несколько фич, которых мне лично не хватало при работе с другим шаблонизатором (конкретнее - с шаблонизатором из Abo.CMS).
В общем, жду ваших мнений по поводу скорости, удобства, полноты документации и всего, что касается работы шаблонизатора. =)

**UPD 02.06.2011**:
Обновил шаблонизатор и ссылку на скачивание.

Ссылка на скачивание - http://narod.ru/disk/14793860001/class.Ltpl.zip

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all('/<block_([^\s>]+)>/', $thtml, $blocks);
// ...
if(strpos($thtml, '<block_'.$blocks[1][$i].'>') === false)
// ...
// здесь еще 2 раза strpos вызывается
$this->children[$blocks[1][$i]]->parse($this->getBetween('<block_'.$blocks[1][$i].'>', '</block_'.$blocks[1][$i].'>', $thtml));
// ... 
$thtml = preg_replace(
            '/<block_'.$blocks[1][$i].'>[\s\S]*<\/block_'.$blocks[1][$i].'>/',
            '<block_'.$blocks[1][$i].'>',
            $thtml
        );
```

Т.е. ваш шаблонизатор для *каждого* блока на *каждой* итерации проходит по *всему* шаблону минимум *4 раза*. Боюсь, что такой шаблонизатор умрет раньше, чем веб-приложение станет чуть сложнее "Hello, World".

Я бы посоветовал вам не изобретать велосипеды, а воспользоваться проверенными годами шаблонизаторами.

[Blitz](http://alexeyrybak.com/blitz/blitz_en.html) - является одним из самых быстрых, легких и лаконичных блочных шаблонизаторов для PHP. Разработан русским программистом и успешно применяется на многочисленных highload проектах (например, на habrahabr.ru).

Comment: Вот. То, над чем я и размышлял - в каком месте оптимизировать. Спасибо. Насчет Блица я посмотрю, возможно, что-то интересное найду. А если велосипеды не изобретать, то можно и мимо мопеда пройти. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var $html;
var $children;
var $shown;
var $tags;
function Ltpl($x = '')
{
}
```

Зачем так делать, смешивать конструкции 4 версии php с пятой.
Неужто так нельзя было записать

```
public $html;

public $children;

public $shown;

public $tags;

function __construct($x = '')
{
}
```

Comment: это совместимость с 4й версией

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите сказать, что ваш шаблонизатор в 4 версии php будет работать?!!!
В 4 версии php не было public, private, protected, собственно говоря поэтому в 4 версии он никак работать не может.
Если делать совместимость с 4 версией, то нужно было всё как var оформлять

Comment: кстати да, не видел что там public есть

Comment: Да, спасибо. Что-то долго думал насчет совместимости, но так и не решил ничего. А потом и позабыл).

Answer (score 1):

Выскажу своё мнение:

1. локализация <s>немного</s> топорная. Используйте базу со структурой аля:
   | id | lang | key | value |
   при обращении создаём файл в виде ru.dat (lang = язык (select key, value from table where lang="ru")) и сериализуем всё (все переводы с языком ru) в этот файл.
   И  при наличии файла брать из него, а не из БД.
2. очень часто требуеться конвертор. Например в переменную у вас приходит timestamp (числовой) и нужно сделать из него дату. Мы в темплейте задаём какой конвертор нужно использовать для получения нужной даты. И при переходе из одного формата в другой не нада менять пхп код, достаточно поменять темплейту.
3. Попытайтесь сделать свой мини-язык. Для этого сначала придумайте синтаксис. Что бы было удобно и минимум телодвижений со стороны пользователя библиотеки. Так же важна область видимости переменных ... возможность использовать массивы в темплейтах (иногда очень удобно)

Посмотрите в сторону smarty (хотя мне он не нравится)
и погуглите на тему "i18n php"

Вы не обижайтесь если резко вас раскритиковал.

Comment: 1) Собственно, так и планировалось, но без сериализации. Немного не догоняю, как в случае надобности быстро править такой файл, не прибегая к сторонним скриптам. 2) За идею - спасибо. Буду думать, как определять, пришла ли дата в свободном формате или timestamp. 3) Ну не, свой мини-язык придумывать не хочется. Нужно, чтобы несведущий в программировании верстальщик мог свободно править шаблоны. Как пример - та же Abo: там кода в шаблонах вообще нет - это все придумывает прогер. А массивы - это те же переменные, но с префиксом.